# Parse html/text document as XML?

Tags: jquery, html, xml, text

How can I parse a document with a text/html header as a xml document with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xmlString = ""; //GET string via ajax or whatever the case might be

if (window.DOMParser){
  parser=new DOMParser();
  xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(xmlString,"text/xml");
}
else {  // For IE
  xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xmlDoc.async="false";
  xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlString); 
}
```

Hope that helps..

Comment: @FractalizeR: No, not in the above snippet atleast. It only loads xml document from a string input. But to further parse/traverse the `xmlDoc` tree, jQuery is the best bet! :)

Answer (score 2):

use ajax request to get the page data and treat it like text data..

```
$.get(URL, params, function(data) {

    //process the data here

});
```